# GeoNode : how to replace a layer in the version 4.0?

Tags: geoserver, layers, update, geonode, replace

In GeoNode, I would like to update layers without creating new ones.
However, I don't see in version 4.0 a way to do that.
There is no "replace layer" button such as in the version 3.1 at least (picture below).

What is the way to update a layer?

[image]